# Does assigning a large, deep object with many constant fields to $scope slow down the performance?

Tags: angularjs

Does assigning a large, deep object with many constant fields to `$scope` causes the `$digest` period to be slower?

I have data entries that is drawn from database, which may consist of many fields but most of them are not displayed on the view. Should I assigning this array of large object directly to $scope or should I iterate through and copy out only needed fields? Which one would be the bottleneck in this case?

Comment: It shouldn't change anything. Accessing foo.bar takes the same time whether bar is the only field of foo or whether there are thousand other unused fields. It'll consume more memory though. Don't pre-optimize.

Comment: @JBNizet Not sure about angular case though, because angular does $watch those variables internally, so there will be many checks inside $digest cycle if angular does a deep watch, which would justify going for copy instead of direct assign

Comment: Right. Deep watches could be a problem. But they're not as used as ref watches, and I would still not try to optimize before an actual performance problem exists. See http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html

Answer (score 1):

Nope it won't, as long as there is no deep watch on these objects, number of properties set on a given scope doesnt affect the watch/digestion performances.

adding stuff to a scope doesnt make it watch it "internally" in any way as long as you dont programmaticaly watch it. (to answer your comment)